# How can I use a Future inside an Akka HTTP Directive?

Tags: scala, akka-http

I currently have a directive that I'm using to secure resources in an Akka HTTP app, like so:

```
def authenticate: Directive1[Login] =
  optionalHeaderValueByName("Authorization") flatMap {
    val accessToken = authz.split(' ').last
    case Some(authz) =>
      LoggedInUser findByAccessToken accessToken match {
        case Some(user) => provide(user)
        case None       => reject(AuthorizationFailedRejection)
      }
    case None => reject(AuthorizationFailedRejection)
  }
```

where `LoggedInUser.findByAccessToken()` makes a blocking query against a database, I would like to switch this for an asynchronous `ask` to an actor which which can provide the same data, I'm OK with passing in the `ActorRef` as a parameter to the directive but I cannot work out how to handle the `Future` that the ask returns.

None of the `Directive1` examples that come with Akka HTTP seem to do this (at least I could;t find any) although there are examples of directives returning `Route` which do.

Is what I want to do even possible? Is a possible approach to create a `StandardRoute` subclass with a field for the user credentials and return that somehow?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. As far as I understand you need something like this:

```
def authenticate: Directive1[Login] = {
  def findByAccessToken(accessToken:String): Future[Option[Login]] = ???
  optionalHeaderValueByName("Authorization").flatMap {
    case Some(authz) =>
      val accessToken = authz.split(' ').last
      onSuccess(findByAccessToken(accessToken)).flatMap {
        case Some(user) => provide(user)
        case None       => reject(AuthorizationFailedRejection)
      }
    case None => reject(AuthorizationFailedRejection)
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this, But how to do the same using forcomprehensive

Comment: Thanks! Any chance getting a working example or a reference to one of exactly that scenario, in an up to date version of akka? this will not compile due to deprecation errors on akka & akka-http versions 2.5.19 & 10.1.8

Comment: I've updated akka-http to 10.1.8 and could compile the code without any problems. What are the exact deprecation errors?